# FragmentManager is already executing transactions on commitAllowingStateLoss()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
```

I've read all StackOverflow questions about that, and nothing helped.
Just wanted to share my experience

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if(condition) replaceFragment()
}

public void replaceFragment() {
    if (fragmentName != null && !this.isDestroyed()) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(container_id, FragmentInstantiate());
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

it is commit()/commitAllowingStateLoss() that caused IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions. NOT commitNow() or executePendingTransactions()

Answer (score 11):

**PROBLEM:**
the problem was that in **synchronous** execution of replaceFragment() in Fragment.onResume() method.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if(condition) replaceFragment()
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if(condition) {
        Observable.fromCallable{}
                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                  .subscribe { replaceFragment() }
}
```

or use Handler to postpone execution of replaceFragment()

```
 new Handler().post { replaceFragment() };
```